# Command Prompt for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a difference in typing in 'rails generate model X' versus 'ruby generate model X'?

For me (and on windows 7), it seems like only the latter works and the former doesn't, which has been a point of confusion for me.

Comment: What version of Rails is this? What directory are you in when you are trying to run this? Are your "former" and "latter" accurate (`ruby` works; `rails` doesn't)?

Comment: rails works and ruby doesn't. I believe I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and the latest version of rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate is a rails script, so it is best used using the rails command as you have seen:

```
rails generate model X
```

if you wanted to use the ruby command, you would have to tell that it is a rails script like so:

```
ruby script/generate model X
```

As said in the comments, keep in mind that this was for rails 2.3 below. If you're using rails 3, it's:

```
ruby script/rails generate model X
```

although I don't know why you would want the additional "ruby script" when typing your command. In addition, you can further shorten rails script commands to:

```
rails g model X
rails g migration addcolumnxtotabley
```

etc. You can also use c and s for console and server respectively like so:

```
rails c 
rails s
rails s -p 4000 (sets the port to 4000 instead of 3000)
rails s -u (if you have ruby-debug19 installed)
```

Comment: If using Rails 3, the latter command should be `ruby script/rails generate model X`. All the files other than `rails` is gone from the `script` directory now.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry just assumed he was using a lower version of rails, since in rails 3, i usually use rails g

Comment: corroded, thanks I think it's making more sense now. I think what's been happening is that I've been shorthanding it somewhat and the book references that I've been using have either been a little bit outdated or just opting for the longer notation for thoroughness sake.

Comment: oh that's awesome! the c and s shortcuts are new to me. thanks again!